# Is is possible to generalize a function and capture its signature in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to create a function that takes an array of functions (all having the same signature) and return a function having the same signature, which in turn runs each one sequentially. Like this:

```
function runAll<F extends (...args: any[]) => void>(...funcs: F[]): F {
  return ((...args: any[]) => {
    funcs.forEach(f => {
      f.apply(null, args);
    });
  }) as F;
}
```

The code as it is compiles and runs fine. But if I take the `as F` cast, typescript compiler refuses the code with:

```
Type '(...args: any[]) => void' is not assignable to type 'F'.
  '(...args: any[]) => void' is assignable to the constraint of type 'F', but 'F' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '(...args: any[]) => void'.ts(2322)
```

Is it possible to capture, generically, the signature of a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On top of answer by Maciej Sikora

Another way to capture the parameters:

```
function runAll<F extends (...args: any[]) => void>(...funcs: F[]): (...args: Parameters<F>) => void {
  return ((...args: any[]) => {
    funcs.forEach(f => {
      f.apply(null, args);
    });
  });
}
```

Note that you cannot use ReturnType<T>, due to covariance in the return type.

Comment: Good alternative!

Comment: Thanks for teaching about the `Parameters` and `ReturnType` utility types;

Answer (score 2):

Function types extending is different that standard type extending, as with standard type we have covariance, so we can use type which is subtype of given type, for function type this is contravariance in arguments and covariance in return type.

It means that function type which extends another function type can have equal or less arguments than extended one and arguments will have more wide type (contravariance) and subtype of given type in return (covariance). For example if we have function `(a: "abc", b: number) => string` then function which extends it will be `(a: string) => "abc"`. As exactly it has less arguments, and return is a subtype of string. Also in common sense it is correct, as we can understand lack of arguments as just simple skipping them. We can even test this in this simple example:

```
type F = (a: "abc", b: number) => string
type G = (a: string) => "abc"

type isGExtendsF = G extends F ? true : false; // evaluates into true
```

Take a look how your generic `F` is behaving if we pass to it functions of type `() => number`:

```
runAll(() => 1, () => 2); // F is inferred as () => number
```

And clearly `() => number` is not the same type we want to return with `(...args: any[]) => void`, it is more narrowed type.

---

If all our function will have the same exact argument types, what I understand from your function body, then we can go into following typyings which focus on arguments:

```
function runAll<A extends any[]>(...funcs: ((...args: A) => void)[]): (...args: A) => void {
  return ((...args: A) => {
    funcs.forEach(f => {
      f.apply(null, args);
    });
  });
}
```

Now we block from using function with different type of arguments. For example such code:

```
runAll((a: number) => a, (b: string) => string); // error functions needs to have the same type
```